# PHP - How to generate Soap request XML from object

Tags: php, xml, soap, request

I have an std object :

```
$args = new stdClass();
$args->userName = 'username';
$args->password = 'password';
$args->criteria->customer->customerId = '0002003';
```

I want create SoapRequest XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="wsclient.dms.tecsys.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <mns1:search xmlns:mns1="wsclient.dms.tecsys.com">
            <arg0>
                <userName>username</userName>
                <password>password</password>
                <criteria>
                   <customer>
                      <customerId>0002003</customerId>
                   </customer>
                </criteria>
            </arg0>
        </mns1:search>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But i can't find solution. Can any one help me.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

By using the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class you can create a soap request easily

Take a look at this

SoapClient: __doRequest — Which performs a SOAP request